# How to send data via using POST in Zend_Rest_Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest

There is the next code:

```
$client = new Zend_Rest_Client('http://test.com/rest');
$client->sendData('data');
```

if i send via `GET` (`echo $client->get()`) it works correct

if via `POST` `(echo $client->post()`) i'm getting the next message "No Method Specified."

how to send post using `Zend_Rest_Client`?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this helps:

```
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com';
$endpoint = '/path/to/endpoint';
$data = array(
    'param1' => 'value1',
    'param2' => 'value2',
    'param3' => 'value3'
);
$client = new Zend_Rest_Client($base_url);
$response = $client->restPost($endpoint, $data);
print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link for the `Zend_Rest_Client` Class as it indicates we can use the public method `restPost()` to perform the post operation.

```
restPost ($path, $data=null)
Performs an HTTP POST request to $path.
```

[http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/zend-framework/1.10.3/class_zend_**rest**_client.html](http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/zend-framework/1.10.3/class_zend___rest___client.html)